# How to compile with Cython using a custom version of Python

Tags: python, cython

When I compile a script using Cython, Python 3.6 is used to generate all the necessary files. How can one use a conda environment running Python version 3.5 to compile a Cython .pyx file on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it from within a sourced conda env? On windows to source your env: `activate <your_env_name>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. It does not work. Unless I don't understand your suggestion correctly, that is not the solution.

Comment: "Doesn't work"--you're going to need to provide more information if you want help. What doesn't work? What exception are you getting?

Comment: "No module named 'script-name'". Also, the generated .pyd file is script-name.cp36-win_amd64.pyd. Notice the cp36 in the file name.

Comment: You need to share the code you're running and the stack trace you're getting please

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had accidentaly activated a different Python environment that uses Python version 3.6. Once I activated the right environment, I managed to compile and run my Cython-built program.

Comment: This solution also worked for me on a MacOS by launching an app I know uses my specific python version. Tho wondering if there's a programatic or pythonic way of doing this within the venv project itself.